# Heap Space with mutable.HashMap

Tags: scala, heap-memory, mutablemap

I'm generating a HashMap where I can estimate the requiered size, for factorials:

```
  import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

  val mm = new HashMap [Int, BigInt] 
  mm.put (0, 1)
  def fak (i: Int) : BigInt = mm.getOrElseUpdate (i, i * fak (i-1))
```

I frequently request the factorial (fak) of primes in ascending order, and like to reach pretty high values (> 10 Mio factorials).

Calling it with about 70000 results in an OutOfMemory-Error: Java Heap Space. I started the program with

```
scala -J-Xmx4G TestFak 70000
```

With 60000 as parameter it works. I guess, it builds 70000 MutableMaps which get frequently thrown away and garbage collected. Since I know the requiered size in advance, is it possible to generate a mutableMap of the right size from start?

The error is thrown in the mm.getOrElseUpdate - Line.

Version:
Scala version 2.11.6 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_66-internal)

Comment: It does not build 70000 maps, there is just one map with 70000 entries. One map entry without any data takes about 36 bytes, 36*70K is about 2.5 gig right there. Plus the actual size of BigInts you are storing (they arent small either). You are just hitting your memory limit.

Comment: @Dima: Hm, according to a fast estimation, 36*70K should be about 2.5M, not 2.5G, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yeah, you are right about that :) YourKit?

Comment: You only need to store the prime ones, right?  Why not throw away all the non-prime ones between p(n-1) and p(n), once you hit p(n)?

Comment: @RexKerr: In fact I need more than just the prime ones. About 50% of all numbers and in the end up to 100 million, so any trick which let's me get 2 times or 10 times what I have will not be sufficient. Meanwhile I tried to store just the last number but even this approach is to slow. It would run, optimistically, in 2 days instead of 1 minute. :) Since it is a quizzle, I don't want to ask for the underlying problem, which seems to need some more mathematical approach. But either I solve this by myself or it will just remain unsolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The factorial of 70000 is huge! The `BigInt` required to store that is going to be fairly large in and of itself! Just to give you an idea, the `BigInt` is probably backed by an `Array[Int]` in Java. That means the total size required to store 1!, 2!, ..., 70000! is going to be `sum_(1 to n) of 4 * log_(2^32) n!` for `n = 70000`, which is on the order of four gigabytes.

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable. I've overseen that. Since I have to go for factorials up to 100 million, I have to find another way to solve the challenge, where this is a part from. :)

Comment: Oops I got the math slightly wrong. Ints are 4 bytes not 8.

Comment: Also, why not just try the normal tail recursive approach? It isn't all that slow...

Comment: Okay nvm... the ordinary tail recursive solution is way too slow.